# Concatenated urls disrupt the CSS

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I am using FlowRouter in my Meteor project. The problem I am facing is when I have simple urls like 'add-user', 'my-profile', the pages are rendered without a problem. Even if I refresh the browser, no problem occurs. However, when I use urls like 'add/user' or 'add-user/:id', if I refresh my page, all the CSS is disrupted

This is my index file:

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>

<!-- BEGIN CORE CSS FRAMEWORK -->

<link href="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-table-responsive.css">

<!-- BEGIN CSS TEMPLATE -->
<link href="assets/css/select-dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/loader.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/custom-icon-set.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/magic_space.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/jquery.tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery.bxslider.css">
<!--<link href="assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />-->

<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/ie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/select-dropdown.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/breakpoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-lazyload/jquery.lazyload.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-numberAnimate/jquery.animateNumbers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/date-time-picker.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico " sizes="32x32" />

</head>

<body>

</body>
```

My files are placed in public/assets folder

Comment: This sounds very odd. But without code there's not much to go on. Meteor *should* package up all the css as a single file, there should be no difference between routes. In fact switching routes shouldn't even cause any other files to be loaded.

Comment: Thankyou @MichelFloyd for your comment. I made a public directory and in that I have called all my assets. My index.html file calls the css and script files like this:
<link href="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
What I noticed was that when I concatenate my URLs like 'user/add' or 'manage-user/1', the browser tries to find stylesheets and scripts files with respect to these links and hence, it doesn't find anything

Comment: You don't need to put your css in the public directory, you don't even need to refer to them in your html files, Meteor will include them all automatically. You're probably using relative paths to refer to them and the other routes are trying to find them lower down than they exist. Please show one of your html files for your routes.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I have included code with my question. Please look into this. If I don't add css files and script files like this, it doesn't pick them up